# Why is this react-bootstrap modal not properly responding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap

I am working on a react-bootstrap web app that uses modal dialogs. Multiple modal dialogs are rendered in the app at different places (e.g. in different components, route/switch constructs, different levels of hierarchy etc.). However, only ever one modal dialog is active at a time.

Until now I never had a problem with that approach (I'm relatively new to react). Somehow I ended up in a situation where two modal dialogs are "semi-frozen"? They each open and close as supposed (and also the buttons work), but I cannot edit the form in them anymore (and also cannot select the header text for example).

Both dialogs were working until I added more dialogs at other places (that's my guess at least). Is there something I need to watch out for when working with multiple modal dialogs? Or more generally like where to render modal dialogs?

[Modal dialogue in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7wpt.png)

```
        <Modal show={show} onHide={discardChanges} backdrop={edited ? "static" : true}
               keyboard={edited ? false : true} size="lg" centered>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>{t("edit tour")}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <TourContainer tourTemplate={editableTourTemplate} pointsOfInterest={pointsOfInterest}
                               dispatch={dispatchEditableTourTemplate} validated={edited} />
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={saveChanges} disabled={!(edited && editableTourTemplate.valid)}>
                    {t("save")}
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={discardChanges} variant="outline-primary">{t("cancel")}</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
```

It is rendered in another component somewhere like this:

```
                                <Col>
                                    <button onClick={showEditModal} className="bg-white border-0">
                                        <img src="/img/pencil.png" alt="Pencil" height="25" width="25" />
                                    </button>
                                    <TourEditModal show={editModalVisible} hide={hideEditModal}
                                                   tourTemplate={tourTemplate}
                                                   pointsOfInterest={pointsOfInterest}
                                                   update={updateTourTemplates.update} />
                                </Col>
```

Comment: My first guess is that the problem isn't in the modal, but in the form. Check your code to make sure you don't have a loop where you both set and change the props to TourEditModal. If those are being modified on load, and that load changes props that trigger another load, that can cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The problem indeed was not with the modals itselves (see answer below). But thanks to you I made a closer inspection and noticed some other issues, I still need to work on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason these two modals were behaving that way was that I moved them inside of a NavLink element. This NavLink element has a preventDefault() on mouse down because I don't like the button focus there. Naturally, the modals became unfocusable.

Once I moved the modals out of the NavLink element they were working as intended again.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem once, my code would look like this.

```
<Modal>
    <Link className='p-3'> <Button> <Add New Record/> </Button> </Link>
</Modal>
```

The Button was very unresponsive.

So what i did is i remove them inside the Link, and make them a single base.